# What is the Angular JS equivalent of this Curl POST command?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, curl

I am trying to program the following Curl command using Angular JS. I'm very new to AngularJS, so I may be missing something fundamental.To be specific, this is a mobile app, that is using the ionic framework (which uses Angular JS)

The curl command is this:

```
curl -X POST  -d "username=xxxx&password=xxxx&action=login&view=console"  http://myserver.com/zm/index.php?skin=xml
```

This works perfectly from command line.

In AngularJS, I have the following code:

```html
angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('MonitorCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $scope,$http)
{
            
console.log("***MAKING REQUEST");
                                                 

//$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                                                 
 $http({
    url:'http://myserver.com:9898/zm/index.php?skin=xml',
    method:'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Accept': '*/*',
       },
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
       var str = [];
       for(var p in obj)
       str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
       var foo= str.join("&");
       console.log ("****RETURNING "+foo);
       return foo;
    },
       data: {username:'admin',
              password:'xxxx',
              action:'login',
              view:'console'}
       
  })
                                                 
.success (function()
{console.log("****YAY");
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
        console.log("***OOPS "+status + " H: "+data);
});
                                                 
                                                
});
```

When I run this code, I see a POST  request going to my server (I am sniffing using httpry) and a 200OK being returned from the server with the required payload, but my success handler is not being called. The error handler is called with a status of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it all out

a) Amir popovich is right in that if I am dealing with XML, I need to 'transmogrify' (transform in a magical manner, for non Calvin and Hobbes readers) JSON to XML. The updated code I posted in my question does exactly that and works. But even after doing all that, my URL post (or get) was failing.

b) The entire darn CORS error I was facing was because I was running this app in a desktop browser (Safari) and it was Safari that was kicking out the response unless it had Accept Origin

c)  When I deployed and tested the app on my phone, it worked like a charm. Don't ask me why

Answer (score 1):

data should be a `json`. It depends on your server.

The common way to do it is is using properties on an object:

```
data: {username: 'xxxx', password: 'xxxx', action: 'login', view:'console'}
```

but if your server receives a string as an input then:

```
data: {key: 'username=xxxx&password=xxxx&action=login&view=console'}
```

Comment: Amir, thanks. converting to JSON does not work. The server rejects the POST. When I keep it as the original string without converting to JSON, I can see the HTTP POST being responded to with a 200 OK and the payload that I am expecting -- just that the 'success' function is not being invoked.

Comment: It depends on how you implement your server. What are you expecting to get on your server?

Comment: Amir, here is a raw dump from the requests and responses via the CuRL command line to show you exactly what works when using curl:

Comment: Oops here is the link: http://pastebin.com/ujLzDyyH
(The server is a 3rd party server - not my implementation)

Comment: I've updated the code to handle JSON to non json formatting, I've validated the server is returning the right response, but my failure handle is being invoked in the app for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Augh. After debugging a lot, I realized the reason AngularJS is not accepting my server's response is because it is not adding a "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'" header in its response. I can't change the server. How on earth can I make my app accept this response?

Comment: Read about cross domain requests on the internet. A quick solution is using JSONP (read about it as well).