# How to convert this PHP CURL to Angular $http.post?

Tags: php, angularjs, curl

At https://github.com/apanzerj/Former-For-Zendesk/blob/Lesson-1-Branch/former.php there is a Zendesk repository for sending the contents of a custom HTML contact form to Zendesk's server.

I'm building an AngularJS website and I'd like to have this same functionality but using Angular's `$http.post` method instead of PHP CURL.

I'm at a loss on how to convert their thing from PHP to Angular though. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Is it even possible to go from AngularJS directly to Zendesk's server, without a server-side language on my end that passes the data?

Comment: It may not be possible if the zendesk server has has their cors turned on.

Comment: True. I guess for purposes of this question let's assume that they do have CORS set to allow third party domains to access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Angular JS equivalent of this Curl POST command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457674/what-is-the-angular-js-equivalent-of-this-curl-post-command)